# Javascript DIV Background issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, html

I currently have a web site in which I am using some Javascript to change the Background of a DIV.

The DIV is defined as follows :

```
<td style="width: 750px; height: 300px; background-color: Black; border: 0px;">
   <div id="outerscreen">
            <div id="mainscreen">
            </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

and the Javascript I am using is as follows :

```
var docEl = document.getElementById('outerscreen');
            docEl.style.backgroundImage = "url('pics/intro.gif')";
```

My problem arises where this function works perfectly on IE but fails for Chrome, FF and Safari.

Can anyone shed any light on what the problem is and how I might be able to resovle this.

Thanks in advance 
Chris

Comment: i suspect that `docEl = document.getElementById(` query is not supported in the other browsers. You will need to identify IE as its the only one that has different access methods.. Hooray

Comment: @ppumkin document.getElementById() is supported in every browser

Comment: why can't you directly write `doc.getElementById('outerscreen').style.backgroundImage =`

Comment: whats width the edit? it made more sense earlier

Comment: working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/net3Y/

Comment: @Ibu didn't change the language, just added the formatting !

Comment: It didn't work on my machine, so I changed the URL to an absolute one: http://jsfiddle.net/net3Y/3/

Comment: A 750x300 table data cell? Are you [abusing tables for layout](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/)?

Comment: i hope you have one and only one element with id = outerscreen.

Comment: Are you running your JS code in the body onload() method?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have some content inside #mainscreen, the most likely explanation is that #mainscreen is floated, so it isn't used when calculating the height of it's parent, but that you have a Doctype (or no Doctype at all) that triggers Quirks mode in Internet Explorer, so it doesn't allow floats to fall through the bottom of their containers.

1. Add a Doctype that triggers standards mode (so IE will be more consistent with other browsers)
2. set `overflow: hidden` on #outerscreen

Answer (score 0):

This does work in FF4 and Opera10. You need to specify the height and width of `<div id="outerscreen">`, or have some content inside which takes up screen real estate for this effect to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Although i don't recommend using a table for your layout here is a solution that works better and gives you more control

```
<style type='text/css'>
   .outerCell {
     width: 750px; height: 300px; background-color: Black; border: 0px;
   }

   .outerScreen {
      background-image : url('pics/intro.gif');
      height: 300px;
   }
</style>

<td class='outerCell' >
   <div id="outerscreen">
            <div id="mainscreen">
            </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

now the javascript:

```
var docEl = document.getElementById('outerscreen');
 docEl.className = "outerScreen";
```

Having your style defined in a css is more flexible when you want to make changes, 
code seperation is always good

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the '

try:

```
docEl.style.backgroundImage = "url(pics/intro.gif)";
```

Comment: `'` characters around urls in CSS only cause problems in IE5 for Mac. This doesn't seem likely.